# Self-healing creep

Tags: javascript, screeps

I want to make a creep that heals it self, but the code below doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
module.exports = function(creep) {
    var targets = creep.room.find(Game.HOSTILE_CREEPS);
        if(targets.length) {
            creep.rangedAttack(targets[0]);
        }
        if(creep.hits < creep.hitsMax) {
                creep.heal(creep);
                console.log("healing")
        }}
```

Comment: Does that Console.log("healing") actually get called?

Comment: It does show up in the console so yes

Comment: Just the ammount of hits stays the same

Comment: So.. where is the code for changing the amount of hits?

Comment: This is also mentioned in the documentation, under Creep in the body part table. For HEAL it says: _Heals another creep restoring 10 hits per tick_. [link](http://screeps.com/docs/Creep.php). It would ruin the gameplay, making it possible to make self-healing creeps that heal so fast they can't die except by expiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the code at https://gist.github.com/avdg/7835babe74904a8a123b is accurate, creeps aren't able to self-heal.
Line 4657 has a set of checks that cause the heal function to do nothing, with no error.
One of the checks is k==b, where k seems to be the target and b seems to be the creep doing the healing. So, if they are the same, it simply does nothing.